# switch class without the previous being read

Tags: jquery, css

I have a CSS3 animation with transitions that take effect based on what is defined in classes that are added, removed, toggled, etc.

So, I have a class '`flyOff`' which is used to; when added, make the element fly up and to the left. When it is removed it flys down / transitions down from that position.

```
$('.exchange-tablet').addClass('transTime flyOff');
$('.exchange_text').fadeOut();
```

This is fine.

**However...**

I need to **bring it back down, from a different position** (specifically from the top right).

When I `removeClass` `flyOff` it flys (transitions) down from the top left as that is defined with `flyOff`.

Problem: I need it to transition down (fly down) from the top right.

So, I created class `.flyOffr` with those defined coordinates of top right.

```
$('.exchange-tablet').removeClass('flyOff').addClass('flyOffr');
```

But when I do the above, it still flys down from the `flyOff` position (top left) - because I guess that is removed before the needed `flyOffr` is attached.

Attempt with `.toggleClass`

```
$('.exchange-tablet').toggleClass('flyOff flyOffr').addClass('complete');
```

`flyOffr` wasn't being read with the above..

The problem is not with CSS margins or coordinates -- because when I add and remove the classes in the console; *eg.* Add `flyOffr` it flys down as needed I just need a solution to transition from the two classes. Without `flyOff` bring read before `flyOffr` does.

So, I'm thinking I need a `.switchClass` solution of sorts. Any pointers?

---

**Update**: What worked (though not as ideal) via @shash7 *(but with some slight tweaking)*

```
   $('.exchange-tablet').removeClass('flyOff');
          setTimeout(function() {
          $('.exchange-tablet').addClass('flyOffr');
          $('.exchange-tablet').removeClass('flyOffr');
    }, 600);
```

Comment: We would need to see the html and CSS for this to troubleshoot properly. The problem is most likely in your CSS. Can you post the rest of your code?

Comment: I'm sorry, what does the HTML markup  have to do with this. When I add remove classes in the console it works -- my problem is transitioning between the classes in a time where the other isn't read before the new attaches.

Comment: _"what does the CSS / HTML markup have to do with this"_ ? _"I have a CSS3 animation with transitions that take effect based on what is defined in classes that are added, removed, toggled, etc"_

Comment: I just think it's a trigger question..

Comment: _"a trigger question.. "_ ? What is a "trigger" question ?

Comment: You are using CSS for the animations. Without seeing the animations, or your non working code in a jsfiddle or similar, it's just taking shots in the dark to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this(assuming your animation takes 250ms):

```
$('.exchange-tablet').removeClass('flyOff');
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.exchange-tablet').addClass('flyOffr');
}, 250);
```

But I highly recommend you don't go down this route. Instead of making classes for moving elements around, add transformation css and a function to add it to the element for programmatically moving elements around.

Or even better, use an animation library like [movejs](http://visionmedia.github.io/move.js/).

Comment: Hey, so I ended up getting it with your method! But with some slight tweaks:        $('.exchange-tablet').removeClass('flyOff');
                                      setTimeout(function() {
                                      $('.exchange-tablet').addClass('flyOffr');
                                      $('.exchange-tablet').removeClass('flyOffr');
                                    }, 600);